# Rotating phone with achievements shown shows strange things

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

In the Android app, I clicked the Achievements in the top bar.  When I rotated my phone, the achievements disappeared ... sort of.  It actually became transparent, so I saw my achievements and my search results at the same time.[image]